# Что такое "прос" в "І на кухні сиджу в пошуках вечорів, відчуваю себе серед тисячі прос"? З пісні гурту SadSvit

Tags: значення-слів

З пісні "[Літо](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpSVSxUQcd0)" гурту SadSvit:

> Качелі самотніх дворів
> Захопив їх назавжди лютий мороз
> І на кухні сиджу в пошуках вечорів
> Відчуваю себе серед тисячі **прос**

Що означає слово "прос"? Я пошукав у [Словнику](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk), але там цього слова немає. Мабуть, це скорочення?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pisni.Org.Ua наводить трішки інший варіант тексту](https://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/5450209.html):

> Качелі самотніх дворів,
> Захопив їх назавжди лютий мороз,
> І на кухні сиджу в пошуках вечорів,
> Відчуваю себе серед тисячі про**з**…

— тобто «серед тисячі проз», від слова [про́за](http://sum.in.ua/s/proza).

І цей варіант суб'єктивно здається мені вірогіднішим, ніж «серед тисячі прос». Мені здається, це просто особливості вимови вокаліста, що вимовив *проз* як *прос*. (Теоретично при правильній вимові *з* у кінці слова не має оглушуватися, але всі ми недосконалі.)

(Також є слово [про́со](http://sum.in.ua/s/proso) з множиною [проса́](http://sum.in.ua/p/8/290/1), але родовий відмінок множини - [просі́в, а не прос](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/). Та й за змістом, мені здається, *проза* підходить значно краще за *просо*.)